# What is the best method to use to write removeSuffix()?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a simple one line method called `removeSuffix()`.

Here are my choices:

```
test.slice(0, test.length - len);
```

or

```
test.substring(0, test.length - len);
```

or

```
test.substr(0, test.length - len);
```

They all do the same thing given this test case:

```
len = 1; // length of the suffix to remove

test = "abcd" // test string
```

Current implementation:

```
function removeSuffix(str, len){
    return str.slice(0, str.length - len);
}
```

Comment: Pick whichever you feel like is more readable. The performance from one method to another is so microscopic you'll never feel the difference.

Comment: Nope, Sarath has a more efficient use of slice.  Got to go with the best.  It removes and unneeded subtraction and replaces it with a negation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about a negative slice
`"abcd".slice(0,-1)`

If you want to pass length make it like

```
var len = 2;    
"abcde".slice(0,-(len))
```

Comment: take out the parentheses around len they add no value.